# API doesn't respond when notifications are sent in bulk

Tags: laravel, push-notification

I have an API in codeigniter and an admin Panel in Laravel both share same database.
Whenever notifications are sent, API takes too long to respond.I don't know why, but I guess because every notification is also saved in database after it is sent.
 But there is no issue in using admin panel, just I can't send other notifications while the later is in progress.
*Number of notficaitons is about 20k to 30k. It's a push notification, sent to android and ios devices with a news in body. It uses firebase.*
And while sending notifications is in the process, devices, android user and ios users, take too time to load other stuff which comes from API developed in codeigniter.

**I want to know If  queuing this process can solve the issue?**
If so, *what should be minimum time delay between two notifications?*

Comment: Depending on what you are doing, queuing can significantly reduce the upfront runtime for bulk actions.  This is because it allows the heavy lifting to happen at a later time rather than making the user wait for completion of the entire task.

Comment: I think your question may be too vague to provide any specific answers.  How many notifications are we talking about?  What does the notification do?  The API "takes too long to respond" to what — the notification, the admin panel, other users?  We have so little to work with and you haven't provided any code.

Comment: @matticustard I updated the question, please see the details. I will appreciate If I get any help or sugestions.